# How to accept or skip the pop up window in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to accept the pop window, if appears or continue if does not not appear.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();


        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("Application URL");
        //Launching the application

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By. id("LoginID")).sendKeys("username");
        //Finding the element by ID and given valid username

        driver.findElement(By. id("Password")).sendKeys("password");
        //Finding the ee=lement by id and given valid password


        driver.findElement(By. id("submit")).click();
        //Clicked on the Log in button


        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

            alert.accept(); 
       //Accepting the pop up window when appears.
```

Comment: What is the popup window? Do you mean a browser alert or an HTML dialog or ? You need to be much more specific or provide a link to the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect alert using try-catch..

```
public boolean isPopedUp() { 
    try { 
        driver.switchTo().alert(); 
        return true; 
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException Ex) { 
        return false; 
    }   // catch 
}
```

and then use this in your code as follows:

```
if (isPopedUp()) {
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
}
```

Comment: The suggestions/errors of eclipse for the above code are Remove invalid modifiers - public boolean isPopedUp(), return true;  - change method return type to boolean, change to return and  if (isPopedUp()) { - Create method isPopedUp. Please suggest me with full code. I am in learning stage...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a popup appears you can use this code to accept..

```
try{   
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();  
    }catch(Exception e){ 
    System.out.println("unexpected pop up not present");   
    }
```

Whenever a popup appears you can use this code to skip..

```
try{   
    driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();  
    }catch(Exception e){ 
     System.out.println("unexpected pop up not present");   
     }
```

Comment: The pop up may or may not appear, if appears i should accept it, if does not appear i should continue with the next element.Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using this..it handles alerts if a alert popup..and u can accept if it popups